# 8 ohm to 4ohm speaker wiring switch query

Tags: switches

I have 2 speaker pa cabs ,2 16ohm speakers in each wired parallel.8 ohms per cab.
My amplifier is 4 ohms.
Can i wire up a DPDT switch to make the cabs 4 ohms..mono,
If yes how do i do it.??
regards for any help.

Andy

Comment: Sounds like you can parallel the two cabinets and get 4 ohms without any switch.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does "pa cabs" mean in this context? I'm guessing (something) cabinets?

Comment: 'Public Address' loudspeaker cabinets.

Comment: Thanks for your help..Mike and Felthry.  PA Cabs are public address cab,s for singing or talking through. like,pa system.regards Andrew.

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ZaY5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Various arrangements for 16 Ω twin speaker cabinets.*

Figure 1 shows your options. You can do the maths yourself.

- If you series the speakers the resistance is \$ R1 + R2 \$.
- If you parallel the speakers the resistance becomes \$ \frac {1}{\frac {1}{R1} + \frac {1}{R2} } = \frac {R1 \cdot R2}{R1 + R2} \$.